# Unwanted result while using .htaccess for 2 rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on a web application with PHP.
I'd like to have clean URLs, so I wrote a .htaccess file for it. Everything is ok, but just for 1 rule.
Look at the code below:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rule No.1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,N]

# Rule No.2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

This is my .htaccess file contents.
If I remove the Rule No.1, and the page be something like `www.site.com/news`, everything works fine. But when I want to navigate to page `www.site.com/news/1/sample-text`, all CSS, JavaScript, and image files will destroy (I have not access to them anymore).
Although I wrote Rule No.2 in .htaccess file, but anything did not work and the problem is steel alive.

All images, css and javascript paths are similar to `./js/jquery.js` format.
 Also, I put `RewriteBase /` in .htaccess file. But ... :(

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Rules will be better if they are like this:

```
# Rule No.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]

# Rule No.2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

=> You need to repeat the RewriteCond lines here: they apply only to the RewriteRule which follows.

Notes:

- NC flag (case insensitivity) is useless here
- the first rule doesn't use $3
- ([^/]+) would make more sense than (.*)

Comment: For css, javascripts and images, you need to use absolute paths (eg /js/jquery.js) or insert a `<base href="..."/>` tag in your page. This is the client which resolves these paths, not the server. The client ignores all of the rewriting.